# To generate one for the first time: rails generate symmetric_encryption:config, how to fix warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

When I start my Rails application I'm getting warning like this

```
Symmetric Encryption config not found.
To generate one for the first time: rails generate symmetric_encryption:config
```

I don't know why it's showing

If I `generate symmetric_encryption:config` nothing happened.

What is the use of **'symmetric_encryption:config'**

Where it will use? What it will do?

Anything we have to configure, and what it will encrypt?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://reidmorrison.github.io/symmetric-encryption/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mean that your application using `symmetric-encryption` gem. [Here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/symmetric-encryption/2.2.0/file/README.md#Installation) is detail information about configuration of this gem.